# How to find where an element's onClick handler is actually added with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools

Using Chrome's developer tools, you can see what events that can be fired by the element have listeners attached. (Inspect an element, find the "Event Listeners" tab in the right part of the developer tools window.) When it's added using some simple JS, clicking on the source link where it's defined will usually take you to a lovely line of calling `addEventListener`. When it's added with jQuery however, you'll probably end up at some minified jQuery blah that starts looking something like this:

```
function _(e) {
    var t = M[e] = {};
    return v.each(e.split(y), function(e, n) {
        t[n] = !0
    }), t
}
```

Now even if I were to look at the non-minified version of this code, it still wouldn't tell me where it was originally called to add the event listener. So how would I do that and finally find out what will actually happen when the event fires?

Comment: `console.log($._data($(selector)[0],'events'));` ??? Then check for each type event, each object handler

Comment: That's… quite awkward and hard to remember… but it works! What is $._data? I can't find jQuery's documentation on it.

Comment: This is not a method publicly supported, that's why there is no DOC on it but this is how jquery deal with bound events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Chrome will point you to the actual code that attaches the event handler, instead of the plugin code that handled the attaching.